# Unshapable list error when scraping information

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to extract information but they will give me error of unshapable list these is page link https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abaewicz-agnieszka-51004

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }


  

    def parse(self, response):
        wev={}
        tic = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//span//text()").getall()
        det = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//div//text()").getall()
        wev[tuple(tic)]=[i.strip() for i in det]
        
        yield wev
```

They will give me output like these:
[image]

But I want output like these:
[image]

Comment: please include the full traceback of the error

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python39\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 858, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "e:\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\sample\sample\spiders\test.py", line 21, in parse
    wev[tic]=det`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `zip()` to group values from `tic` and `det`

```
        for name, value in zip(tic, det):
            wev[name.strip()] = value.strip()
```

and this will give `wev` with

```
{
    'Status:': 'Były adwokat', 
    'Data wpisu w aktualnej izbie na listę adwokatów:': '2013-09-01', 
    'Data skreślenia z listy:': '2019-07-23', 
    'Ostatnie miejsce wpisu:': 'Katowice', 
    'Stary nr wpisu:': '1077', 
    'Zastępca:': 'Pieprzyk Mirosław'
}
```

and this will give `CSV` with correct values

```
Status:,Data wpisu w aktualnej izbie na listę adwokatów:,Data skreślenia z listy:,Ostatnie miejsce wpisu:,Stary nr wpisu:,Zastępca:
Były adwokat,2013-09-01,2019-07-23,Katowice,1077,Pieprzyk Mirosław
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you should first get rows and later search `name` and `value` in every row.

```
        all_rows = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']/div")
        
        for row in all_rows:
            name  = row.xpath(".//span/text()").get()
            value = row.xpath(".//div/text()").get()
            wev[name.strip()] = value.strip()
```

And this method sometimes can be safer if some row don't has some value. Or when row has unusuall value like `email` which is added by JavaScript (but `scrapy` can run JavaScript) but it keep it as attributes in tag `<div class="address_e" data-ea="adwokat.adach" data-eb="gmail.com">`

Because only some pages have `Email` so it may not add this value in file - so it need to add default value to `wev = {'Email:': '', ...}` at start. The same problem can be with other values.

```
       wev = {'Email:': ''}

       for row in all_rows:
            name  = row.xpath(".//span/text()").get()
            value = row.xpath(".//div/text()").get()
            if name and value:
                wev[name.strip()] = value.strip()
            elif name and name.strip() == 'Email:':
                    # <div class="address_e" data-ea="adwokat.adach" data-eb="gmail.com"></div>
                    div = row.xpath('./div')
                    email_a = div.attrib['data-ea']
                    email_b = div.attrib['data-eb']
                    wev[name.strip()] = f'{email_a}@{email_b}'
```

---

Full working code

```
# rejestradwokatow

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'test'

    start_urls = [
        #'https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9',
        'https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abaewicz-agnieszka-51004',
        'https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/adach-micha-55082',
    ]

    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        # it may need default value when item doesn't exist on page 
        wev = {
            'Status:': '',
            'Data wpisu w aktualnej izbie na listę adwokatów:': '',
            'Stary nr wpisu:': '',
            'Adres do korespondencji:': '',
            'Fax:': '',
            'Email:': '',
        }

        tic = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//span//text()").getall()
        det = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//div//text()").getall()

        #print(tic)
        #print(det)
        #print('---')

        all_rows = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']/div")

        for row in all_rows:
            name  = row.xpath(".//span/text()").get()
            value = row.xpath(".//div/text()").get()
            if name and value:
                wev[name.strip()] = value.strip()
            elif name and name.strip() == 'Email:':
                # <div class="address_e" data-ea="adwokat.adach" data-eb="gmail.com"></div>
                div = row.xpath('./div')
                email_a = div.attrib['data-ea']
                email_b = div.attrib['data-eb']
                wev[name.strip()] = f'{email_a}@{email_b}'

        print(wev)

        yield wev

# --- run without creating project and save results in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(TestSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: thank it work but some link has email but they do not provide they give none can you help they also provide email this link has email also https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/adach-micha-55082

Comment: Can you update code they also give me email

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to put email in table - but scrapy CAN'T run JavaScript. Normally it would need to use `scrapy` with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. There is even module [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/). But I see it send HTML with `'<div class="address_e" data-ea="adwokat.adach" data-eb="gmail.com"></div>'` so mail can be created using values from `data-ea` and `data-eb`. I will create code soon.

Comment: I added code which gets email from `'<div class="address_e" data-ea="adwokat.adach" data-eb="gmail.com"></div>'`

Comment: I had to add default value for some items because it doesn't add them when they don't exists on some pages. It may need to other other values to `wev = {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys cannot be mutable and must be hashable.  Try this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    wev={}
    tic = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//span//text()").getall()
    det = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//div//text()").getall()
    wev[tuple(tic)]=[i.strip() for i in det]
    print(wev)
    yield wev
```

or even simpler:

```
def parse(self, response):
    tic = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//span//text()").getall()
    det = response.xpath("//div[@class='line_list_K']//div//div//text()").getall()
    yield {tuple(tic): [i.strip() for i in det]}
```

Comment: how can I `yeild` it

Comment: I have add the  pic I want output  like these in format

Comment: THe ouput will give me but the format I want they don't give us in csv file

Comment: can you tell me  it possible?

Comment: @amenaziz I don't know what you are asking...  it sounds like you need to read the python tutorial

Comment: Can you see the pic  I have add?

Comment: in question it will better for you understanding what I am asking

Comment: @AmenAziz  to convert to csv output you can either write a different script for that or change some of the settings in `settings.py`.   The instructions are here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=csv#csv

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of `tic`. It is most probably a list that cannot be dictionary keys. Maybe you can cast it to a tuple based on your requirements.

Comment: how create tuple

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).